# Filter the source of ActionPerformed on a combo box

Tags: java, swing, events, listeners

I have 2 combo boxes. **The upper combo** box dynamically **changes the items on the second combo box.**

How can the ActionPerformed event know, that the event was triggered because the upper combo box changed the items?

I tried to 
I set actioncommands to both combo box. (Upper and lower). When the upper combo box changes the items on the lower combo box, i get the command lower because it changed it...

EDIT: i changed the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should use the actionCommand:

```
//after object creation:
upperCombo.setActionCommand("upper");
lowerCombo.setActionCommand("lower");
```

And then in your actionPerformed():

```
String command = event.getActionCommand();
if("upper".equals(command)){
  //Do something
} else if("lower".equals(command)){
  //Do something
}
```

Does this solve your problem, or did I misunderstood you?

EDIT:

What about somthing like this:

```
String command = event.getActionCommand();
if("upper".equals(command)){
  lowerCombo.removeActionListener(this);
  //Do your changes
  lowerCombo.addActionListener(this);
} else if("lower".equals(command)){
  //Do something
}
```

EDIT (again ;)):

```
class YourClass{
 private ActionListener lowerActionListener = new java.awt.event.ActionListener() { 
   void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    //doSomething 
   }
 };

 //...
 // maybe in the constructor, after object-creation
 lowerCB.addActionListener(lowerActionListener);

 //...
 // in th actionPerfomed() method
 lowerCB.removeActionListener(lowerActionListener);

}
```

Comment: You understood me right, but I explained my problem wrong :( Look at my discription again, I edited it

Comment: @user3549340 Is the following what you mean? You change the content of the second combo, after that a event is triggered by the second combo, because its selection / content has changed. You want to avoid this one? right?

Comment: lowerCombo.addActionListener(this); when I use "this" it thinks that it's the JPanel (or the class I don't know). It wanted that I make a cast but it didn't work. How should I write in ActionPerformed?

Comment: You must have an object, which implements your actionPerformed()-Method (because it implements the ActionListener Interface). replace "this" with your ActionListener object.

Comment: cb.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
     void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    cb(evt);
    }
    );     and in the void cb I'm doing that. Do you mean that? btw sorry for format. No idea how to do it in comments

Comment: its an anonymous class, this makes it much harder. Just Extract the ActionListener to a variable like this: (edit in progress)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the normal solution is to have two action listeners, one for each combo box.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the point. After changing the second combobox, it fires an ActionEvent, which he/she wants to avoid.